# Mule ESB cxf client config

Tags: esb, mule

I'm using mule cxf client to consume web services. How can I change default configuration of the mule cxf client? What I need is to change "Keep-Alive header". Other option is to change http protocol version to set it to 1.0, if that is posible? Thank you.

```
<cxf:jaxws-client operation="updateParcelDetails"
                  clientClass="com.pb.pts.service.endpoint.TrackingserviceV10"
                  port="ParcelTrackingServiceEndpoint_V1_0Port"
                  wsdlLocation="classpath:wsdl/TrackingV10.wsdl" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled by the HTTP transport, not the CXF module.

The [HTTP transport doc says](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/HTTP+Transport+Reference#HTTPTransportReference-OutboundendpointTheHTTPoutboundendpointallowsMuletosendrequeststoexternalserversorMuleinboundHTTPendpointsusingtheHTTPprotocol.):

> Attributes of `<outbound-endpoint...>`
>
> **keep-alive** | `boolean` | Controls if the socket connection is kept alive. If set to true, a keep-alive header with the connection timeout specified in the connector will be returned. If set to false, a "Connection: close" header will be returned.

Have you tried it?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have added keep-alive="false" to <http:endpoint>. We are testing it now.